# how update decimal fields from one table to other in mysql

Tags: mysql

Fields lng and lat are decimal fields in each table.

```
update s
join t on s.id = t.id 
set s.lat = t.lat , s.lng = t.lng
where  s.id = t.id and (conditions)
```

In same select-query after running this update-query I not see difference  - seem that UPDATE didn't run.
Someone have idea ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, put conditions first and set after that

```
UPDATE s
JOIN t on s.id = t.id and (conditions)
SET s.lat = t.lat , s.lng = t.lng
```